# Does using multiple ActionMailer classes increase memory overhead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, actionmailer

I'm currently using two Mailer classes in my Rails 3.2 app. One is **AdminMailer,** dedicated to sending emails to the internal team, and one is **UserMailer** to send emails to our registered users.

UserMailer is beginning to feel bloated, with 35 methods (i.e. 35 different emails) in it and counting. I could definitely take a subset of these emails that fit under a theme, and extract them out into a third Mailer class to make the code more manageable and readable.

**My question is:** Does it introduce more memory overhead on the app to need to instantiate more Mailer classes?

I tried searching for this on Google & Stack Overflow but didn't seem to find anything on the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every request in Rails initialises about ~50k objects. One class more or less doesn't not make much difference. for instance basecamp3 has over 40 mailers (source: https://twitter.com/dhh/status/656905137898786816).

Splitting mailers to many classes make is much easier to test (single responsibility, less stubbing/mocking).

Don't worry, split them to many classes! Won't affect your performance. Most of 'waiting time' in Rails comes from database interaction. Optimising Ruby code is in most cases just a micro-improvmenet comparing to database operations time